# Identify which frame is currently displayed in EBImage shiny-display

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have written a shiny-app using the EBImage bioconductor package to perform cell segmentation from microscope images. I can then extract the segmented cells as an image stack using the `stackObject()`' function and display these using the `display()` function.

I now need to know which frame is currently being displayed as I will annotate each frame with a species identification within my shiny app (using this in the long term to build a training dataset for a convolutional neural network to automate cell ID).

I cannot find a way to identify within the shiny app which frame is currently being displayed.

This is my first stack overflow post so please excuse if the format of this request is not ideal. For example, I am unsure how to upload a file to use as the input image stack here, but I have given a basic code example *without the data* below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(EBImage)

ui <- dashboardPage(

dashboardHeader(title = 'test display'),

dashboardBody(
    displayOutput('img1', width = '100%', height = '600px')
             )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$img1 <- renderDisplay({
        display(**Image Stack Here**)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question, "I need to know which frame is currently being displayed" refers to which frame in the **original image** that was used to generate the stack with `stackObjects`, it may just require mapping the frame in the stack to the objects from the mask used to generate the stack. If so, perhaps this example can help. This finds odd sized nuclei to display in a stack with frame information. There is nothing unique to `shiny` in this approach.

```
# Use cell nuclei example from EBImage
  library(EBImage)
  nuc <- readImage(system.file('images', 'nuclei.tif', package='EBImage'))

# Create nuclear mask
  nmask <- thresh(nuc, 10, 10, 0.05)
  nmask <- opening(nmask, makeBrush(5, shape = "disc"))
  nmask <- fillHull(nmask)
  nmask <- bwlabel(nmask)

# Find very small and very large nuclei in each frame
  area <- apply(nmask, 3, function(x) table(x[x > 0]))
  typical <- lapply(area, function(x) which(x > 150 & x < 750))
  mask <- rmObjects(nmask, typical)

# Create stack of oddly sized nuclei
  stk <- stackObjects(mask, nuc)

# Determine frame in stack from frame in mask with findInterval
  nmax <- apply(mask, 3, max) # note that nuc had 4 frames
  index <- c(1, cumsum(nmax))
  query_frames <- c(1, 2, 15, 16, 27, 36) # random frames in stack
  findInterval(query_frames, index, rightmost.closed = TRUE)
```

This mapped the values in `query_frames` to the four frames in the original nuc image. Here's another application of this principle building on the objects used here.

```
# Map object in stack to original frame from nuc
  dm <- dim(stk) # stack dimension (40 objects)
  nobjects <- tail(dm, 1)
  idx <- seq_len(nobjects) # index of each frame in stack
  frame <- findInterval(idx, index, rightmost.closed = TRUE)

# Visualize with frame label in upper 10% of each panel
  nx <- 8
  ix <- (idx - 1) %% nx
  iy <- (idx - 1) %/% nx
  plot(stk, all = TRUE, nx = nx)
  text(dm[1]*(ix + 0.1), dm[2] * (iy + 0.1), frame, col = 2, adj = c(0, 1))
```